# Matlab Gui update plot with popmenu

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a matlab Gui program which takes input data from the serial and plot them in an graph. The Gui has several tabs. In the second tab I have a popmenu which allows me to select the data to plot.

**The callback function**

```
function popupCallback(src,~)
    val = get(src,'Value');
    % Second tab selected
    if val == 2
        try
            while (get(xbee, 'BytesAvailable')~=0 && tenzo == true)
                % reads until terminator
                sentence = fscanf( xbee, '%s');

                % Collect data to plot
                getDataRoutine(sentence)

                %Plot them            
                h1 = subplot(3,1,1,'Parent',hTabs(3));
                plot(h1,index,gxdata,'r','LineWidth',2);
                h2 = subplot(3,1,2,'Parent',hTabs(3));
                plot(h2,index,gydata,'b','LineWidth',2);
                h3 = subplot(3,1,3,'Parent',hTabs(3));
                plot(h3,index,gzdata,'g','LineWidth',2);
            end
        end
    end
```

When I select the second option in the popmenu the string from the serial is analyzed, data are stored in variables and then plotted. Fine.

**The problem:**

Data are plotted only when I click on the second option in the popmenu. How can I get data plotted in 'real time'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I used three timers to perform the plot task at a constant rate of 0.1s

Declare timers first.

```
global gyroTimer;
gyroTimer = timer('ExecutionMode','FixedRate','Period',0.1,'TimerFcn',{@graphGyro});

global angleTimer;
angleTimer = timer('ExecutionMode','FixedRate','Period',0.1,'TimerFcn',{@graphAngles});

global accTimer;
accTimer = timer('ExecutionMode','FixedRate','Period',0.1,'TimerFcn',{@graphAcc});
```

In the popmenu callback function start the right timer when the corresponding option is selected

```
% drop-down menu callback
function popupCallback(src,~)
    %# update plot color
    val = get(src,'Value');

    % Gyro
    if val == 2            
        start(gyroTimer);
        stop(angleTimer);
        stop(accTimer);
    end

    % Accelerometer
    if val == 3
        stop(gyroTimer);
        stop(angleTimer);
        start(accTimer);                    
    end

    % Magnetometer
    if val == 4
       stop(gyroTimer);
       start(angleTimer);
       stop(accTimer); 
    end
end
```

Create the plot function

```
function graphAngles(obj,event,handles)
    % To debug uncomment the following line
    %disp('Angles');

    h1 = subplot(3,1,1,'Parent',hTabs(3));
    plot(h1,index,Tdata,'r','LineWidth',2);
    hold on;
    plot(h1,index,EKXdata,'b-','LineWidth',1);
    hold off;

    h2 = subplot(3,1,2,'Parent',hTabs(3));
    plot(h2,index,Pdata,'r','LineWidth',2);
    hold on;
    plot(h2,index,EKYdata,'b-','LineWidth',1);
    hold off;

    h3 = subplot(3,1,3,'Parent',hTabs(3));
    plot(h3,index,Ydata,'r','LineWidth',2);
end
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

The key is what a trigger event you want to use. If you want it is automatically updated when you select the second tab, you should take the action 'select the second tab' as your trigger event for the update of the plot.